# $_GET from generated list is undefined on display page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a generated number of elements from a mysql databas which are displaying correctly and have their primary id's also attached.

I want that when one of the elements is selected onClick (using 'a') that a jquery is sent to the database to recall more information on this chosen element and is displayed on this main page.

The problem is that the primary id that is chosen is not getting through to my fetch page where the further information from the database call is formatted and returned to the display page.

I think the error is in here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
       $('a').click(function() {    
        var id = $(this).val('myval'); 

        $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to foliobase.php
        type: "GET",

        //link to the foliobase.php file "?subj" here is the connector///
        url: "foliobase.php?subj="+id,          
       dataType: "html",              
       success: function(response){                    
      $("#fillFolio").html(response); 
     }
  });
});
});
</script>
```

and especially this part because when I put the folio_id number in directly after ?subj= instead of +id, it all works fine:

```
var id = $(this).val('myval');
```

this is the generated table of elements:

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from portfolio");
  print "<ul>";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
  print  "<li><a href=\"javascript:return(0)\" myval=".$row['folio_id'].">  <div class=thumbnails><img src={$row['image']}></a></td></li>";
}
print "</ul>";

?>
```

Here is the fetch page which has the mysql query and layout of information which is to be returned to the display page:

```
$folio = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection, $_GET['subj']);

//I'm getting exists here!!!!!!!
if(!empty($_GET)){
echo "exists";
}
else{
echo "do not exist";
}

?>
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from portfolio WHERE folio_id='$folio'");
```

I'm still coming to grasps with Javascript, jquery, ajax etc and have been on this for days before I would think of asking stackoverflow for help, so thanks in advance.

Comment: Try using this, and let me know if that works `var id = $(this).data('myval'); ` and  `data-myval=".$row['folio_id']."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead use `attr()`:

```
var id = $(this).attr('myval');
```

or you can make use of `data-*` attribute:

```
print  "<li><a href=\"javascript:return(0)\" data-myval=".$row['folio_id']."...</td></li>";
```

and then you can use:

```
$('a').click(function() {    
    var id = $(this).data('myval');

});
```

Answer (score 1):

myval is not a valid html attribute.

Your php should output something like this:

```
<?php
    $query = mysqli_query($connection, "select * from portfolio");
    print "<ul>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
        print  "<li><a href=\"javascript:return(0)\" data-myval=".$row['folio_id'].">  <div class=thumbnails><img src={$row['image']}></a></td></li>";
    }
    print "</ul>";
?>
```

Your jQuery code should be like this:

```
var id = $(this).data('myval');
```

Comment: Thank you both, you are both correct and it worked, Unfortunately I can only give one tick. Never saw the "data-" part being used before.